# How to get channel related data from youtube api

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-channels

I need to get the video/playlists/show data from youtube.com.

Example :

- http://www.youtube.com/channel/SWMb9NxQL9I6c
- http://www.youtube.com/show/mtvroadies9/featured

Is there a way I can get the video details for the above URL using the youtube API?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, using:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels

e.g.

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&id=SWMb9NxQL9I6c&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the [`YouTube Data API`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/). You will find there documentation about how the API can be accessed. You can also find [client libraries](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/libraries).

You could also make the requests yourself. Here is an example URL that retrieves the latest videos from a channel :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={your_key_here}&channelId={channel_id_here}&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=20"
```